# Fiddling with CMS CSS whitespace

Tags: css

I have a logo wrapped in a div with `class="title-logo-wrapper fl"`

I am trying to remove (or decrease) whitespace between my logo and the main nav.

The div contains the `a` and `img` elements but looking at "inspect element" these do not appear to be the problem. It is the `div`.

I cannot figure out how to remove the whitespace between the bottom of the logo and top of the main navigation.

Since I am using a CMS, there is quite a chunk of HTML code between the two elements. I am reluctant to add it to the question.

Would anyone mind taking a quick peek here: http://tinyurl.com/ovstqug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#header hgroup {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't see any space and I see your rule applied so I guess it worked! :D

Comment: Thank you very much accepting when the timer limit allows. I should have added to the question, how did you figure out what selector to use? Using inspect element only the div with class="title-logo-wrapper fl" came up. I then looked at "DOM properties" in Chrome inspect element and could not figure out. Is there a best approach to finding what element to manipulate?

Comment: :) In the inspect element, when you hover the mouse over an element, its box is shown on the main view. So I simply found your problematic element, and hovered the elements around it to see which one has the box in the whitespace you want removed. It had to be a child of the title-logo-wrapper.